# Bootstrap datatables + mysql custom query

Tags: php, mysql, datatable, datatables

I like using bootstrap data tables from datatables .net but I think they have limited possibilities. Or - my knowledge is limited. Let's say I would like to use following mysql query to display specific data:

```
SELECT 
    table_a.id, product_name, customer_name, location, phone
FROM
    table_a
        INNER JOIN
    table_b ON table_a.product_id = table_b.product_id
        INNER JOIN
    table_c ON table_a.customer_id = table_c.customer_id
```

or that one:

```
SELECT 
    wizard
FROM
    table1
        LEFT OUTER JOIN
    table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

How can I use such query? regular version of the datatales.net doesn't allow to use left join / outer join - right? or I'm in a huge mistake? I was trying to find proper answer, yet all directs me to wrong place (datatables EDITOR which I don't want to use..). Thanks!!

Comment: I think you'll need to write your own script to get what you want, but don't too disheartened as it's not all that hard (I even managed it (http://drmsite.blogspot.co.uk/2015/03/datatables-custom-server-side-script.html)). You need to target (PHP probably) script to read and return the data according to the specification here: https://datatables.net/manual/server-side

Comment: You can create a [`view`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-view.html) out of your query and use that view as table source for dataTables.